# Serving a dynamically generated image to a chatbot

Tags: node.js, image, express

i am currently working on a chatBot using nodejs. I dynamically generate an image based on user input then store in a folder to serve it as a static file using express to the user. the thing is that i don't need the image any more after it has been served and i worry that the idea of storing the images in a folder in the project will affect the scalability of the project. i thought of using a mongodb data base to store the image then delete after but feels like overkill for such a project. i would like to know if there is a better method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may serve as base64 string image without saving it into the database or into the public folder of your application. Means create it on the fly and serve it to the user with the API.